# Instantiating inherited Constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have two classes A (superclass) and B (subclass) as shown below. I used `super()` keyword along with parameters to instantiate the constructor of the super class. However, I'm looking another elegant way of doing this rather than listing all the parameters of the super class in the sub class since it becomes lengthy when the number of attributes for the super class is huge.

```
public class A {

    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;

    public A (String a1, String a2, String a3){
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
    }

    public void setA1(String a1){
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getA1(){
        return a1;
    }
    ...
}

public class B extends A{

    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;

    public B (String b1, String b2, String b3, String a1, String a2, String a3){
        super(a1,a2,a3);
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

    public void setB1(String b1){
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public String getB1(){
        return b1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have to provide those parameters somewhere, this is the most elegant way.

Comment: Consider creating a class to encapsulate the parameters. (BTW, you are calling the constructor, not instantiating the constructor. That is something else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other way would be to use Composition instead of Inheritance. There are more benefits in this method, which you can read about. But anyways, it is going to be something like this:

```
public class A {

    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;

    public A (String a1, String a2, String a3){
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
    }

    ...
}

public class B {
    private A a;
    private String b1;
    private String b2;
    private String b3;

    public B (A a, String b1, String b2, String b3){
        this.a  = a;
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

    ...
}
```

You have probably noticed that this method is scalable, you can extend it to more number of parameters. For example, you can take this to one more step to make it like the following:

```
    public class A {

        private String a1;
        private String a2;
        private String a3;

        public A (String a1, String a2, String a3){
            this.a1 = a1;
            this.a2 = a2;
            this.a3 = a3;
        }

        ...
    }

    public class B {

         private String b1;
         private String b2;
         private String b3;

        public B (String b1, String b2, String b3){

            this.b1 = b1;
            this.b2 = b2;
            this.b3 = b3;
        }

        ...
    }

    public class C {
        private A a;
        private B b;


        public B (A a, B b){
            this.a  = a;
            this.b  = b;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> However, I'm looking another elegant way of doing this rather than listing all the parameters of the super class in the sub class since it becomes lengthy when the number of attributes for the super class is huge.

Well, the elegant way is to avoid having a "huge" number of parameters. If you find that you have a large number of parameters, consider:

- Splitting the class in two (or more) pieces, as often a large number of parameters is a sign that a class has more than one responsibility
- The builder pattern (or some variety of it), which would avoid this duplication *and* make construction clearer

Constructors aren't inherited in Java, and there's no way to *make* them inherited.